# Python: appending array to a new array based on dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, append

For example, my clusters has the follow:

```
cluster = {0: [array([ 0.66979552,  0.25469174])],
 1: [array([-0.69608797,  0.91087328])]}.
```

And I want to append X[j] to dic(0) . Say X[j] is.

```
X[j] = array([ 0.83563669, -0.33302472])
```

I used the append function

```
cluster[0].append(X[j])
```

and got KeyError for doing so.

So please help, how can I append an array to a new array based on certain dictionary.

Comment: What's your full error? It works for me.

Comment: Also what should the final output be?

Comment: What is the error (include the full stacktrace) and what is the expected result?

Comment: The expected is result is cluster = {0: [array([x1,y1]), array([x2,y2])], 1: [array([-0.69608797,  0.91087328])]}.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
cluster = {0: [[ 0.66979552,  0.25469174]],
 1: [[-0.69608797,  0.91087328]]}

x =[0.83563669, -0.33302472]

cluster[0].append(x)
```

Gives:

```
{0: [[0.66979552, 0.25469174], [0.83563669, -0.33302472]],
 1: [[-0.69608797, 0.91087328]]}
```

Remove the "array" arguement.

Comment: the array argument is from numpy, which is why I have to keep it as it is a numpy array

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand that you want say. But, I did this:

$ python

```
>>> cluster = {0: [ 0.66979552,  0.25469174],1: [-0.69608797,  0.91087328]}
>>> j = 3
>>> X={}
>>> X[j] = [ 0.83563669, -0.33302472]
>>> cluster[0].append(X[j])
>>> cluster
{0: [0.66979552, 0.25469174, [0.83563669, -0.33302472]], 1: [-0.69608797, 0.91087328]}
```

Comment: the array argument is from numpy, which is why I have to keep it as it is a numpy array